# How to generate SQL table structure as a text table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, structure

Ho to export MySQL table structure as text version table?

I mean something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| EID       | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| MOD_EID   | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| EXIT_TIME | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm sure there is some tool which will export table like this. Does anyone know how to do this from MySQL?

Comment: what do you mean by export? are you expecting something like *`create table ...`* to be `dump`ed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could accomplish that with 3 ways.

- DESC : ease of use
- SHOW CREATE TABLE : ease of create new table with another table's same schema
- information_schema : difficult to use, but powerful.

**1. using DESCRIBE**

```
DESC $DB_NAME.$TBL_NAME;

sample output
mysql> DESC jsheo_test.test;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spent  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**2. using SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE $DB_NAME.$TBL_NAME; 

sample output
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE jsheo_test.test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**3. using information schema**

```
SELECT  TABLE_NAME
   , COLUMN_NAME 
   , ORDINAL_POSITION
   , DATA_TYPE
   , IS_NULLABLE 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = '$DB_NAME'
   AND TABLE_NAME = '$TBL_NAME'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;

sample output
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE |
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| test       | name        |                1 | varchar   | YES         |
| test       | age         |                2 | int       | YES         |
| test       | spent       |                3 | int       | YES         |
| test       | gender      |                4 | char      | YES         |
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

**4. from shell**

*run use `-e` option*

```
$  mysql -uusername -S ~/tmp/mysql.sock -e "DESC jsheo_test.test"
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spent  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

otherwise output format is strange. something like below.

```
$ echo "desc jsheo_test.test;" | mysql -uusername -S /tmp/mysql.sock
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
name    varchar(10)     YES             NULL
age     int(11) YES             NULL
spent   int(11) YES             NULL
gender  char(1) YES             NULL
```

Comment: How do you get text like table, I mean data wrapped with `+---------+` lines?

Comment: @zur4ik do you want to that with only SQL, without programming language?

Comment: Yes. For example I want to post on website some part of my table and I want to achieve result wrapped with "+---------------+` lines.

When I run query from Command Line it returns me cozy string of result, not organized like this.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can SELECT some fields and store them in a OUTFILE with this command:

> SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE 'textile.txt'

Comment: when I do this, I outputs table data without "---" and  "|" simbols, I mean it has not table style

Answer (score 1):

the mysql command line tool allows you to do that with the command

```
desc tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for

```
$>SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
INTO OUTFILE '/PATH/TO/TEXTFILE.TXT'
```

OR

```
$>mysql -h<mysqlhostname> -u<username> -p <databasename> -e "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME" > myfile.txt
```

Replace the SQL.